# Chart.js - Increase spacing between legend and chart

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have a bar chart where I have drawn 3 vertical lines, each with it's own label at the top. I would like those labels to be above the top of the y-axis (above the 30% line in the example) but below the legend.  I can't figure out how to increase the space between the top legend and the chart such that I can have my vertical line labels (15, 24 & 33) be off of the chart itself but below the legend.  Any ideas?

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, since there is no config option to handle this the only way you can achieve the desired result is to extend Chart.Legend and implement the `afterFit()` callback.

Here is a quick [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeOYdL) showing how to do just that.  To change the spacing, just change the value in line 9 (currently set to 50).  Also, this of course only works with the legend at the top.  Hopefully, the example is clear enough for you to modify in case you want to move your legend elsewhere.

Comment: I understand the basic concept of what you did here, though I would never had a chance on my own.  Thanks.  This works perfectly!!

Comment: Ok, so perhaps you can help with one minor issue.  This solution looks perfect, but I can no longer click on the individual items in the legend to toggle the data on and off.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @BryanLewis In the codepen example, I'm able to click on the legend items without any issue (is it not working for you in the codepen?) If you are talking about your specific implementation (not codepen example) then make sure you copy line 13 - 60 in my example (its what allows the clicks to behave correctly)

Comment: Your codepen example works and I copied everything, but it still doesn't work for me.  I think something else in my chart.js code may be interfering.  I will test further.  Thanks.

Comment: @jordanwillis I tried your codepen sample. It worked but in my case legends were aligned in center after applying this legends are no longer center aligned. Legends are at top position.

Comment: When you say center aligned do you mean your legend position is set to left? If so then you need to adjust the `width` property in the new legend instead of the `height`. If that is not what you meant then I'm not sure what you mean by center aligned.

Answer (score 45):

If you want do increase spacing in all charts you can put this code before creating :

```
Chart.Legend.prototype.afterFit = function() {
    this.height = this.height + 50;
};
```

Of course, I don't try but i think you can change it (or copy the original Chart object before, to keep the original padding).

Bye,

Comment: This works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I posted that 2 years ago, I think there is a trick to do this if the legend is below

Comment: @DorianMaliszewski Ah nice, do you have a link? I'm currently going through the rounds myself trying to fix this issue...

Comment: @DorianMaliszewski any updated version? Granted I'm very new to chartjs, but it doesn't appear to work with 3.9.1.

Comment: this no longer works at all in newer versions.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to apply padding below legend **for some charts only** in your app:

**ChartJS >= 2.1.0**

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  id: 'paddingBelowLegends',
  beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
    chart.legend.afterFit = function() {
      this.height = this.height + 50;
    };
  }
});

// ----------------------------------
// disable the plugin only for charts
// where you DO NOT WANT the padding
// ----------------------------------

// for raw ChartJS use:
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  config: {
    plugins: {
      paddingBelowLegends: false
    }
  }
});

// for angular-chartjs:
$scope.myChart.options.plugins = { paddingBelowLegends: false }
// then in template:
// <canvas class="chart ..." chart-options="myChart.options" ... />
```

**ChartJS >= 2.5.0**

Specific plugins for each chart are supported, it should be possible to do:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [{
    beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
      chart.legend.afterFit = function() {
        this.height = this.height + 50;
      };
    }
  }]
});
```

See [ChartJS documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) + inspired by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957884/488666)

Answer (score 25):

If anyone is wondering why the `afterFit` solution is not working in Chart.js 3.3.0 it is because the `afterFit` function was removed from the legend plugin.

If you want to make this work anyway by taking advantage of the `fit` function, you can try this hacky solution / workaround:

```js
const plugin = {
  beforeInit(chart) {
    // Get a reference to the original fit function
    const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;

    // Override the fit function
    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      // Call the original function and bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
      originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
      // Change the height as suggested in other answers
      this.height += 15;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that this is not an ideal solution, but until we have native support for this legend padding, I'm afraid this is as good as we can do right now.

Comment: For when the legend's position is set to Left you can change the width instead of the height. Any idea how to adapt this for when the legend's position is Right or Bottom?

Answer (score 8):

This helped me after 2 days of research.

```
Chart.Legend.prototype.afterFit = function() {
    this.height = this.height + 50;
};
```

update this in module.ts file

Comment: Same answer as above

Comment: I've added where you should update it in angular project.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using react-chartjs-2 (but this is just a port and uses the same configurations object) and I was able to achieve that by changing the labels configuration nested on legend configuration:

```
chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      padding: 50 -> this one.
    }
  },
```

You can check the property description here:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does add some padding to multiple rows of legend items, but it doesn't explicitly add whitespace between the legend and the graph.

Comment: Also, note that the path is chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.padding

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply padding below legend for some charts only in your app:

#### ChartJS >= 2.1.0

Note: make sure to add this in `plugins` and not inside `options.plugins`.

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  id: 'paddingBelowLegends',
  beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
    chart.legend.afterFit = function() {
      this.height = this.height + 50;
    };
  }
});

// ----------------------------------
// disable the plugin only for charts
// where you DO NOT WANT the padding
// ----------------------------------

// for raw ChartJS use:
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  config: {
    plugins: {
      paddingBelowLegends: false
    }
  }
});
```

For React Users using `react-chartjs-2`:

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";
  ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);
<Line
        data={{
          datasets: trendsData?.map((trend, idx) => ({
            type: "line",
            label: trend.domainName,
            data: trend.domainTrends.map(d => d.value),
            backgroundColor: getDomainColor(idx).backgroundColor,
            borderColor: getDomainColor(idx).color,
            pointRadius: 0,
            tension: 0.3
          })),
          labels: trendsData?.[0]?.domainTrends.map(d => d.date)
        }}
        options={{
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: true,
              align: "start",
              labels: {
                font: { size: 14 }
              }
            }
          }
        }}
        plugins={[
          {
            id: "increase-legend-spacing",
            beforeInit(chart) {
              // Get reference to the original fit function
              const originalFit = (chart.legend as any).fit;
              // Override the fit function
              (chart.legend as any).fit = function fit() {
                // Call original function and bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
                originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
                this.height += 20;
              };
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the above approaches on my react(react-chartjs-2) project but no luck. Here I have one different approach like creating custom legends outside the chart. so you can get more control over it

1. Hide default legend
2. Get legend object using any ref method.
3. Loop and make a custom legend using html and css.
4. Sample [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-ivdoq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I am aware that OP is not about reactjs component, but as it is a common issue it will help someone.

[Orginal reference](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/issues/81#issuecomment-546125187)

.

Answer (score 2):

For `ng2-charts@^3.1.0`, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67723827/5706293) works with an addition:

```
this.options.labels.padding = 40;
//this.height += 15;
```

or the `title.padding` config (this'll create an invisible title under the graph so it's a bit hacky):

```
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        title: {
          display: true,
          padding: 10,
        },
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-t7b1td?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&preset=node)

Comment: title actually adds some padding but it is located just above the lexend box, in the position that OP set up its legend.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `react-chartjs-2` library to show chart in a React app. You can use the below solution:

```
const plugin = {
  beforeInit: function (chart) {
    // Get reference to the original fit function
    const originalFit = chart.legend.fit

    // Override the fit function
    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      // Bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
      originalFit.bind(chart.legend)()
      this.height += 20 // Change the height
    }
  }
}

export const ReactChart2Example = (props) => {
  const { data = [] } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart plugins={[plugin]} type ="bar" data={data}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

We have to pass `plugins` prop separately in React js Chart component and not inside `options`.

Reference: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10388#issuecomment-1217363379

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what OP really wants but at least for newer versions, and the one I used - 4.0.1 - there is no way to increase the margin between the legend box and the chart, that I have been able to find at least, so this is a workaround. In order to avoid this problem:

[image]

I had to change the position of the legend box below the chart with these option configurations:

```
options = {
    layout: {
        padding: 30
    },
    parsing: {
        key: 'nested.value'
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            color: '#36A2EB'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            align: 'center',
            labels: {
                padding: 20,
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Note: To add the values at the top of the bars I had to add the npm package chartjs-plugin-datalabels with the following features inside your datasets config:

```
datasets: [
    {
        label: "Ejercido",
        data: source.map( s => s.ejercidoTotal),
        datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        clamp: true,//this makes one datalabel not visible if it crashed with other one
        display: 'auto',
        align: 'top',
        color: '#333333',
        formatter
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

With this as the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If using `react-chartjs-2` and want to avoid using a custom plugin, then a hacky solution is to use a fake x-axis with an empty label.

```
<Chart options={{
  scales: {
    x: {
      // Your real x-axis options
    },
    xTopPadding: {
      // Fake x-axis for padding
      position: 'top',
      labels: [''],
      grid: {
        drawOnChartArea: false,
        drawTicks: true,
        ticksWidth: 0,
        ticksLength: 0, // Increase ticksLength to increase the "padding"
      },
    }
  }
}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching the chart.js file I found out that the height of the labels bar is defined there in

```js
height = this._fitRows(titleHeight, fontSize, boxWidth, itemHeight)
```

OR

```js
this.height = Math.min(height, options.maxHeight || this.maxHeight)
```

in the fit() function

```js
fit() {
const {options, ctx} = this;
if (!options.display) {
  this.width = this.height = 0;
  return;
}
const labelOpts = options.labels;
const labelFont = toFont(labelOpts.font);
const fontSize = labelFont.size;
const titleHeight = this._computeTitleHeight();
const {boxWidth, itemHeight} = getBoxSize(labelOpts, fontSize);
let width, height;
ctx.font = labelFont.string;
if (this.isHorizontal()) {
  width = this.maxWidth;
  height = this._fitRows(titleHeight, fontSize, boxWidth, itemHeight);
} else {
  height = this.maxHeight;
  width = this._fitCols(titleHeight, fontSize, boxWidth, itemHeight);
}
this.width = Math.min(width, options.maxWidth || this.maxWidth);
this.height = Math.min(height, options.maxHeight || this.maxHeight) + 40;}
```

And I changed it to +40 as shown above. and it worked fine for me so I wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with bar charts. In the end I found a workaround instead of AfterFit method to solve the issue.

My original chart looks like this
[original chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNbGr.png)

And after I added the following options to my chart,

```
options: {
           scales: {
                y: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  grace: '5%',
                }
              },
            },
```

Final image is [final charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoRxE.png). This workaround worked for me. Grace is adding kind of padding at the top of the chart.
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=3Pss5GvlPd0&ab_channel=ChartJS

Answer (score -9):

You can use layout property under options. This helped me:

```
   layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 50,
            right: 130,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. This is the padding around the entire canvas, not between the legend and chart.