# Chart.js - Increase spacing between bottom legend and chart

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

i'm trying to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart) but with legend on bottom.
When i try adding it at most i can get something like this:  [image]

i'm considering separating legend to another div like

```
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

but it would be nice to achieve it with the former solution.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Related - [Increase spacing between legend and chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42585861/104380)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

```
plugins: [{
          beforeInit: (chart, options) => {
            chart.legend.afterFit = () => {
              if (chart.legend.margins) {
                // Put some padding around the legend/labels
                chart.legend.options.labels.padding = 20;
                // Because you added 20px of padding around the whole legend,
                // you will need to increase the height of the chart to fit it
                chart.height += 40;
              }
            };
          }
        }]
```

Comment: Can I just say how much of a legend you are ;)

Comment: @LostSoul you made my day.

Comment: If you have more than one line with Labels, this is not the desired solution.

Answer (score -4):

you can use margin-top for #js-legend.

Comment: Can't really do that while using former solution because it's being drawn on canvas...