# How to expand the slice of donut chart in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

Is there any way to expand the slice of donut chart onclick event or mouse hover in chartjs ?.
I am using chart.js@2.8.0 version.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift-zooming the currently selected slice is not a feature but it has been discussed several times on various forums and the project's GitHub community:

- https://forum.mendixcloud.com/link/questions/85582
- https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1451

The Github discussion contains a fiddle someone wrote for a Pie chart with Chart.js 1.0. Here is an updated version for the current Chart.js version that supports Donut charts.

**Code:**

This part only shows the part that zooms the active element, it is just to give you the idea of how to use the active elements `.innerRadius` and `.outerRadius` properties to shift the element. The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/fhqk9xct/) contains the complete code that also handles shrinking the previously selected element.

```html
<div style="width:400px;">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: 30
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [4, 5, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 3
      }]
  }
});

var addRadiusMargin = 10;

$('#myChart').on('click', function(event) {
  var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);

  if (activePoints.length > 0) {
    // update the newly selected piece
    activePoints[0]['_model'].innerRadius = activePoints[0]['_model'].innerRadius +
        addRadiusMargin;
    activePoints[0]['_model'].outerRadius = activePoints[0]['_model'].outerRadius +
        addRadiusMargin;
  }

  myChart.render(300, false);
}
```

**Sample image:**

Here is a sample of the highlighted slice:

[image: sample]

**Limitations:**

There are two limitations of the sample that I haven't included:

- Chart.js does not allow to define a margin between legend and chart content so when you are "zooming"/"moving", the zoomed slice might overlap parts of the legend. You may solve this by extending the legend as shown in [Jordan Willis' Codepen](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeOYdL) which was the result of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart).
- The selected slice will stay in contact with the remaining slices. If you want it to have a gap, you need to translate `x` and `y` of the active slice based on the `.startAngle` and `.endAngle`properties of the active slice.

Comment: Yes, Thats what I looking for, Thanks !

Comment: That fiddle link you have in there was so useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed this issue using the following code:

```
   let segment;
   this.chart = new Chart(this.canvas, {
    type: this.type,
    data: this.data,
    options: {
      ...this.options,
      onHover: function (evt, elements) {
        if (elements && elements.length) {
          segment = elements[0];
          this.chart.update();
          selectedIndex = segment["_index"];
          segment._model.outerRadius += 10;
        } else {
          if (segment) {
            segment._model.outerRadius -= 10;
          }
          segment = null;
        }
      },
      layout: {
        padding: 30
      }
    }
  });
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Works great, though it seems to not work with most of ChartJS's easing options

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Another simple trick : `hoverBorderWidth`

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Microsoft Internet Explorer", "Google Chrome", "Mozilla Firefox", "Opera", "Safari"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Number of votes',
            data: [60, 20, 10, 8, 5],
            backgroundColor: ['#96ceff', '#424348', '#91ee7c', '#f7a35b', '#8286e9'],
            borderColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBorderColor: ['#96ceff', '#424348', '#91ee7c', '#f7a35b', '#8286e9'],
            hoverBorderWidth: 8
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            displayColors: false
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
```