# Accessing a slice of a react-chartjs Pie chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to create a static (non-clickable) Pie chart using `react-chartjs-2`.
However I want one of the slices to "pop out", or appear bigger than the others:

[image: Visual example of the pie chart I'm trying to create]

**Hence, I'm trying to access one of the slices in the pie chart and modify its `outerRadius` property.**

---

I've encountered multiple similar questions both in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222748/how-to-expand-the-slice-of-donut-chart-in-chartjs) and in [Github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1451), which helped me come up with this:

```js
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

<Pie
    data={data}
    options={options}
    getElementsAtEvent={(elems) => {
        // Modify the size of the clicked slice
        elems[0]['_model'].outerRadius = 100;
    }}
/>
```

However I didn't find anything about getting a slice to pop out without the user clicking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking under `Pie` component's hood, I ended up finding the answer.
You can find it inside `componentDidMount()`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

class PieChart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const change = {
            sliceIndex: 0,
            newOuterRadius: 100
        }
        const meta = this.pie.props.data.datasets[0]._meta;
        meta[Object.keys(meta)[0]]
            .data[change.sliceIndex]
            ._model
            .outerRadius = change.newOuterRadius;
    }

    render() {
        const data = {
            type: 'pie',
            datasets: [ { data: [10, 20, 30] } ],
            labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        };
        const options = {};

        return <Pie
            ref={(self) => this.pie = self}
            data={data}
            options={options}
        />
    }
}

export default PieChart;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one more solution with version 4.3.1.
Try to add **offset** property into **datasets**.

```
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

<Pie
    data={
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [1, 1],
          borderColor: ['black', 'transparent'],
          offset: [10, 0],
        },
      ],
    }
/>
```

It will render Pie with 2 segments. For the first segment, you will have *black* border and **10px offset**