# Chart.js Legend Padding-Left

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have been playing with the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart) from user Frosty Z (chart.js 2.5+) to try and apply padding to my legend. The solution works great if the legend is above the chart but trying to add padding in between the chart and legend when the legend is on the left right side is proving difficult.

```
    plugins: [{
        beforeInit: function(pdChart, options) {
            pdChart.legend.afterFit = function() {
                this.width = this.width + 50;
            };
        }
    }],
```

The picture below depicts my legend as of right now. Again I am hoping to add space between the legend and the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a custom [`HTML` legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) using `legendCallback` together with some `CSS`.

```
legendCallback: chart => {
  let html = '<ul>';
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
    html += '<li>' +
      '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor + '; border:' + ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
      '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
      ds.label + '</span>' +
      '</li>';
  });
  return html + '</ul>';
}
```

> Note that the default legend must be disabled through the option `legend.display: false`.
>
> To make this still behave the same as standard Chart.js charts, the function `onLegendClicked` is invoked when a mouse click occurs on a legend label. This function toggles the hidden state of individual datasets and changes label text style between normal and strike-through.

```
function onLegendClicked(e, i) {
  const hidden = !chart.data.datasets[i].hidden;
  chart.data.datasets[i].hidden = hidden;
  const legendLabelSpan = document.getElementById("legend-label-" + i);
  legendLabelSpan.style.textDecoration = hidden ? 'line-through' : '';
  chart.update();
};
```

The `padding` of the legend is defined through `CSS` as follows:

```
#legend {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code sample and see how it works for your particular case.

```js
function onLegendClicked(e, i) {
  const hidden = !chart.data.datasets[i].hidden;
  chart.data.datasets[i].hidden = hidden;
  const legendLabelSpan = document.getElementById("legend-label-" + i);
  legendLabelSpan.style.textDecoration = hidden ? 'line-through' : '';
  chart.update();
};

const chart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [205, 275, 359, 329],
        borderColor: "#fd7730",
        backgroundColor: "#fd7730",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [262, 302, 290, 180],
        borderColor: "#ffd35c",
        backgroundColor: "#ffd35c",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        data: [359, 329, 262, 302],
        borderColor: "#3fc6f3",
        backgroundColor: "#3fc6f3",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 4',
        data: [105, 175, 259, 129],
        borderColor: "#28a745",
        backgroundColor: "#28a745",
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 5',
        data: [189, 222, 201, 158],
        borderColor: "#488cf2",
        backgroundColor: "#488cf2",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    legendCallback: chart => {
      let html = '<ul>';
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
        html += '<li>' +
          '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor + '; border:' + ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
          '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
          ds.label + '</span>' +
          '</li>';
      });
      return html + '</ul>';
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 100
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

```css
#chart-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#legend {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px 5px 0;
}

#legend li span {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-wrapper">  
  <canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
  <div id="legend"></div>
</div>
```