# Chart JS, strike through external legend when data disabled

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For my [Chart JS](https://www.chartjs.org) use, I use an external legend via a callback, because some data sets have a *lot* of labels.

Example of how the external legend is rendered:

```
            options: {
                legend: { display: false },
                legendCallback: function(chart) {
                    var text = [];
                    text.push('<div class="collapse_container"><div class="collapse_header">Click to show legend</div><div class="collapse_content"><div class="body group"><ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">');
                    for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++)
                    {
                      text.push('<li id="labelLinuxDistributionsCombined' + i + '" onClick="toggleLabels(' + i + ', ChartLinuxDistributionsCombined)" style="cursor:pointer;user-select:none;float: left; padding: 2px; margin: 0 7px 7px 0; line-height: 15px;">');
                      text.push('<div style="float: left; width: 15px; height: 15px; background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].borderColor + '">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;' + chart.data.datasets[i].label);
                      text.push('</li>');
                    }
                    text.push('</ul><button class="chart-toggle" onClick="toggle_all_Labels(ChartLinuxDistributionsCombined)">show/hide all</button></div></div></div>');
                    return text.join("");
                  },
```

This allows people to hide the legend too in a collapsable div.

Now I also have this code, that allows people to click on a legend item label to disable/enable the data set on the chart:

```
function toggleLabels(index,chart)
{
    var ci = chart; //Chart
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
    
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
    
    // We hid a dataset, rerender the chart
    ci.update();
}
```

This all works great! However...

Is there a way I can adjust that, so when clicked/unlicked the label text has a strikethrough?

Comment: Does one of these answers help you solving your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389544/2358409 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64303517/2358409