# How do I increase the space between the Legend and the Chart when using angular-chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm using angular-chart.js to create a chart and have increased the point size quite a bit (8 from the default of 5) to improve visibilty for our users. Doing so makes the points of the line chart overlap the Legend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the implementation of the fix from this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411810, from this post: [Chart.js - Increase spacing between legend and chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart)...

In whatever controller you've got setup, add an `angular.module('graph').config()` (".config block") so that you can access the `ChartProvider` and through it, access the `Chart` object:

```
angular.module('graph')
.config(function ($windowProvider, ChartJsProvider) {
  // Storing ChartJs on $window via $windowProvider.$get() in case
  // we need to do other stuff from directly within a Controller.
  let
    ChartJs =
      $windowProvider.$get().ChartJs =
        ChartJsProvider.$get().Chart;

  // Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411810/7577883
  ChartJs.Legend.prototype.afterFit = function () {
    // You can change the height to whatever pixel value you need.
    this.height = this.height + 32;
  };
})
.controller('graphController', graphController);

function graphController($window) {
  // Example of your controller needs to do and/or options it needs to set.
  $scope.graphingData =       [ /* Your Data           */ ];
  $scope.graphingSeries =     [ /* The Series          */ ];
  $scope.graphingOptions =    [ /* ChartJs Options     */ ];
  $scope.graphingColours =    [ /* Chart Colour Scheme */ ];
}
```

In the template:

```
<canvas 
  id="line" 
  class="chart chart-line" 
  chart-data="graphingData"
  chart-series="graphingSeries" 
  chart-options="graphingOptions"
  chart-colors="graphingColours"
></canvas>
```

I would have added this as a comment to the referenced answer but my account's rep. was too low being a new account.

I truly hope this info helps someone out there! Thanks to the folks who got me onto the right path!!!