# Increase padding between legend and chart with react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I am trying to increase spacing between legend labels and chart with `reactjs`, I've looked for different solutions but most are with vanilla js. I've added this in my chart options based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153992/11866037)

```
  const DoughnutOptions = {
    plugins: [
    {
      beforeInit: function (chart, options) {
        chart.legend.afterFit = function () {
          this.height = this.height + 50;
        };
      }
    },
      {
        labels: {
          render: "percentage",
          fontColor: ["black", "white"],
        },
      },
    ]
   }

  return (
         <Doughnut
            data={DoughnutData}
            options={DoughnutOptions}
          />
       )
```

[image]

But it's not working, am I missing something here ?