# React-chartjs-2: How to add space between Chart and Legend?

Tags: react-hooks, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to add a space between the actual Chart and the Legend/labels. 
Legend has a position rigtht and I don't know how to add a padding/margin between Chart and labels.
Found some discussions but not relevant to react hooks.
From what I understood, I need to make use of `beforeinit` built in function.

Here is the code snippet and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mirzakhani-xnn80r?file=/App.tsx:0-1359).

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

export const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

export function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px" }}>
      <Doughnut
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              position: "right",
              rtl: true,
              labels: {
                usePointStyle: true,
                pointStyle: "circle",
                padding: 20
              }
            }
          }
        }}
        data={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js - Increase spacing between legend and chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add space but increase the width of the legend using the `beforeInit` plugin ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-minsky-dyl22j?file=/App.tsx:1421-1457)). Increasing the width adds some space but it decreases the overall width available to the chart, so you might have to tweak that a little -

```
const plugin = {
  beforeInit(chart) {
    console.log("be");
    // reference of original fit function
    const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;

    // override the fit function
    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      // call original function and bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
      originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
      // increase the width to add more space
      this.width += 20;
    };
  }
};

<Doughnut
        plugins={[plugin]}
...
```